# Issue using Terminal

Tags: java, android, windows, terminal, emulation

I am using Android Terminal Emulator to allow me to move 'non-movable' apps onto SD CARD(External storage). When I enter pm get-install-location I get this message:

Here is the exception

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Neither user 10010 nor current process has android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS.
```

How can I get permission for this? And what are next steps to allowing non-movable apps onto an external sd card.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1):

WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS is not available for normal applications, it's only available fo system app.